# Windows ms-dos command - create lots of SAME subfolders under EACH parent 3rd level folder

Tags: windows, command-line, command, dos, subdirectory

I have a folder structure like this:

```
world
    country
        city1
        city2
        city3
        ...
```

Because of my job, I needed to create lots of SAME subfolders under EACH city. I searched google but couldn't understand the codes since I know nothing about dos environment. Visually I need:

```
world
    country
        city1
            subfolder01
            subfolder02
            subfolder03
            ...
        city2
            subfolder01
            subfolder02
            subfolder03
            ...
        city3
            subfolder01
            subfolder02
            subfolder03
        ...
```

How can I achieve this automatically once by using Windows 7 command?

sorry for I couldn't wrote anything like "I tried but ..." because I even couldn't tried anything.
thanks

BR

### update

**my actual folder names includes spaces and numbers!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, look at the output and remove the `echo` if it is OK:

```
@echo off & setlocal
set /a cityfolders=10 &REM number of subfolders in each city

set /a cityfolders+=100
for /d /r %%i in (world\*) do for /d %%j in ("%%i\*") do (
    for /l %%a in (100,1,%cityfolders%) do (
        set "folder=%%a"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "folder=%%~j\subfolder!folder:~-2!"
        echo md "!folder!"
        endlocal
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /D %%V in ("C:\FOLDER\\SUBFOLDER\\*") DO (
 md %%V\\"subfolder01"
 md %%V\\"subfolder02"
 md %%V\\"subfolder03"
 )
Echo "DONE!"
```

If this doesn't work as path is too deep and/or has many 'special characters' in folder names, such as space, "-", etc, one has to either:
 **a)** move the target folder to the root of the same drive (*maybe rename it too e.g. to "aaa"*), modify path in batch above, execute it and move folder back to it's original place
or
**b)** use VB script instead of windows batch:

```
Option Explicit

Dim myFolder, mySubs

myFolder="C:\folder\subfolder"
mySubs="foo,uncleFoo"

Call AddSubFolders(myFolder,mySubs)
Call MsgBox ("Done!")

Sub AddSubFolders(targetFolder,subFolderList)
Dim FSO, targetF, subF, subSubF
Dim sFoldList, iC

    sFoldList = Split(subFolderList, ",")
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set targetF = FSO.GetFolder(targetFolder)
    Set subF = targetF.SubFolders
    For Each subSubF in subF
    For iC = 0 To Ubound(sFoldList)
        Call FSO.CreateFolder(subSubF & "\" & sFoldList(iC))
    Next
    Next
    Set subF = Nothing
    Set targetF = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Create a file and name it e.g. "runme.vbs", copy-paste code above, change "myFolder"'s value to the actual target folder's name and "mySubs"'s value to a comma separated list of folder names you'd like to add as subfolders, and run it

Comment: is this a batch file format? I mean should I customize & save your code into a txt file like sample.bat and then run? Or? thanks, BR

Comment: aye, simply copypaste into a txt and run. don't forget to change the path, though ;)

Comment: I made it run but the code splitted my existing folders. For example: `My Folder Tree` became `My` and `Folder` and `Tree`. It was 1 folder but became 3 folders.

Comment: Also another comment during my path customization, I should print it like `C:\world\country` for the correct level; right?

Comment: yes, it's "C:\world\country". to avoid splitting, use quotation marks... e.g. md %%V\"folder name with spaces" (EDIT: updating answer to clarify q&a)

Comment: unfortunately same result, I will try `'` instead of `"` now

Comment: same result with `'` also :-(

Comment: I think code has some problem with numbers in folder names. Maybe if everything in folder names was alphabet character, it would work fine but it's still destroying the structure.

Comment: hahh! tricky, you are. plan "B", modifying script :)
EDIT: mod. done, use the new script. worked for me this time with spaces in names as well as numbers (tried with "AAA 111" :P)

Comment: maybe this helps first to you then to me: My actual parent path is: `K:\\RTF\\3.YENI-RTF UNITS\\5. RTF\\PROJECTS\\JTLV-8\\*`

Comment: it's "K:\", not "K:\\"; you need double "\\" only after drive letter, to separate folders
EDIT: updated answer for a better understand. ie first "\" is single, the rest are double.
If still doesn't work I'd recommend moving "JTLV-8" to the root of "K" drive, execute folder-adding batch and move back in place. As it's move on same drive, will be done in a brief moment but these folder names can confuse batch files "a little bit" :)

Comment: again created some weird sub-folders and then created desired sub-folders in SOME folders. I really appreciated your help. But may be I need a more revolutionary code. If you have still energy and patience thanks in advance for your future help.

Comment: have you tried moving the folder in question to "K" root? it's windows batch, no revolutions there. You can use vbs to do the job properly but that's not bat...

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant but I have to quit. Thank you so much